# Отображение картинок в ином размере

Tags: python, qt, imageview

Добрый день!
Осваиваю python и pyqt. Делаю просмоторщик фотографий. Решил отображать картинку с помощью QPixmap в QLabel, но в этом случае label растягивается для отображения картинки попиксельно в максимальном разрешении, что очень неприятно выглядит.
Подскажите какими методами пользоваться для отображении картинки в ином размере. Или  есть вариант - показывать переррисованную картинку?

Comment: Через сам QPixmap можно менять размер: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled

Answer (score 2):

Для масштабирования картинки в `QLabel` можно воспользоваться методом `QLabel.setScaledContents(bool)`. При установке данного параметра в `True`, картинка будет подогнана под размер вашего QLabel.