# Проблема с QMainWindow.resizeEvent()

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пишу GUI с помощью PyQt5, столкнулся с проблемой некрасивого визуально маштабирования главного окна приложения. Захотел исправить это с помощью resizeEvent(), но мой вариант не работает.

Подскажите в чем ошибка :)

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        """
        Здесь описывается графическая состовляющая программы
        (кнопочки, лэйблы...)
        """


class MainWindow_class(Ui_MainWindow):
    """
       В этом классе описаны функции работы приложения
    """
    # конструктор класса
    def __init__(self, form):
       self.setupUi(form)
    # метод который никак не регирует на изменение размеров окна, во всяком случае у меня :)
    def resizeEvent(self):
        print("Алилуя!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindow_class(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Напишити в чем заключается "некрасивое визуальное маштабирование".

Comment: Некрасиво получается, когда отображаются картинки через QLabel с помощью QPixmap - картинка растягивает QLabel. А хочу, чтобы при изменении размеров окна, изменялись размеры картинки, например с помощью scaled().
А как в моем случае переопределить QMainWindow?

Comment: По поводу масштабирования изображение в QLabel посмотрите ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625720/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA/625952#625952

Для этого вам не понадобится переопределять метод `resizeEvent`.

Comment: но в этом случае картинка легко сможет терять свои изначальные пропорции.
Или есть способ закрепить за QLabel пропорции?

Comment: Для охранения пропорций лучше всего сделать класс наследник `QLabel` и там переопределить метод `resizeEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто добавили метод `resizeEvent` в класс `MainWindow_class`, а не переопределили метод в `QMainWindow.resizeEvent`, поэтому у вас и нет реакции на ваш метод.

Вот так можно решить проблему с неработающим resizeEvent'ом:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self):
        """
        Здесь описывается графическая состовляющая программы
        (кнопочки, лэйблы...)
        """
        print("Setup ui:", self)


class MainWindow_class(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """
       В этом классе описаны функции работы приложения
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def resizeEvent(self, *args):
        print("Алилуя!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow_class()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!